# Stockfish 9 giving erroneous reading

Tags: stockfish

Sam Loyd, 1860

```
[fen "8/8/8/8/B6n/7p/6k1/4K3 w - - 0 1"]

1.Bd7!! h2 2.Bc6 Kg1 3.Bh1!! Kxh1 4.Kf2.
```

(Ke1, Ba4; Kg2, Nh4, h3) says mate in 54  after 1.Bd7!! h2 2.Bc6 Kg1 3.Bh1!! Kxh1 4.Kf2.

This is a textbook draw, as the king is on the same square as the knight (with Black to move). For example, in some moment 1...Nf4+ 2.Kf1 Ng3+ 3.Kf2 Ne2 4.Kf1. (No. 205, BCE. Fine.)

Mate in 54? What's up with that?

[image]

Comment: Why is the knight on a different square, and where is it saying mate in 54?

Comment: Stockfish returns a draw score in both your screenshot and the original game pgn.

Comment: Its only mate when the analysis evaluation is prefixed with a `#`, as in `#3` for white or `#-3` for black

Answer (score 4):

Stockfish 10 of lichess @ depth 74 says it's draw. Only if you can give more details about the version of Stockfish you used

[image]

Comment: See edit, please.

Comment: I agree with Intertial Ignorance [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/24230/18143) in this case. Stockfish just couldn't find a forced win so he do a simple material comparaison and by the looks of it, black is completely winning. If you try to follow to main lines you'll see that it never shows in # (mate) in x moves always a material advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Mmm that's not mate in 54, just a -52.40 evaluation (equivalent of being "52.4 pawns" down).

The engine is calculating far ahead and can't find a forced win, but sees Black's up a pawn and knight so it evaluates based off that. I'm surprised the engine wasn't smart enough to evaluate as a draw though, especially if you're using current Stockfish?